# How to examine the feature weights of a Tensorflow LinearClassifier?

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, classification, linear-regression

I am trying to understand the [**Large-scale Linear Models with TensorFlow**](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/linear) documentation. The docs motivate these models as follows:

> Linear model can be interpreted and debugged more easily than neural
>   nets. **You can examine the weights assigned to each feature** to figure
>   out what's having the biggest impact on a prediction.

So I ran the extended code example from the accompanying [**TensorFlow Linear Model Tutorial**](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/wide). In particular, I ran the [**example code from GitHub**](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.3/tensorflow/examples/learn/wide_n_deep_tutorial.py) with the `model-type` flag set to `wide`. This correctly ran and produced `accuracy: 0.833733`, similar to the `accuracy: 0.83557522` on the Tensorflow web page.

The example uses a `tf.estimator.LinearClassifier` to train the weights. However, in contrast to the quoted motivation of being able to examine the weights, I can't find any function to actually extract the trained weights in the [**LinearClassifier documentation**](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/LinearClassifier).

**Question**: how do I access the trained weights for the various feature columns in a `tf.estimator.LinearClassifier`? I'd prefer to be able to extract all the weights in a NumPy array.

**Note**: I am coming from an R environment where linear regression / classification models have a `coefs` method to extract learned weights. I want to be able to compare linear models in both R and TensorFlow on the same datasets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After training the model with Estimator, you could use the [tf.train.load_variable](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.3/api_docs/python/tf/train/load_variable) to retrieve the weights from checkpoint. You can use [tf.train.list_variables](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.3/api_docs/python/tf/train/list_variables) to find the names for model weights.

There are plans to add this support in Estimator directly also.

Comment: Thanks, do you have a link to discussion about adding this to Estimator?

Comment: This is directly supported in `tf.estimators` now:
    `wt_names = model.get_variable_names()`
    `wt_vals = [model.get_variable_value(name) for name in wt_names]`